# How do i change text inside a button with if-else statement?

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement, web

Im on a dynamic webpage written in php and would like to have an if else  statement that would look inside mysql database table and check if the string  "description" is present inside a certain database table column. if the word "description" is present echo "Visit Discounted Venue" text inside the button, else echo "Visit venue website" string inside the button.

I currently have the code below, its in a php file.

```
<?php if(stripos( $forum_data['venue_url_text'],"discount") == false) ?>
<a href="<?php echo $forum_data['venue']['venue_url']; ?>" class="btn" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> VISIT VENUE WEBSITE</a>
<?php elseif: ?>
<a href="<?php echo $forum_data['venue']['venue_url']; ?>" class="btn" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> VISIT DISCOUNTED VENUE</a>
<?php endif: ?>
```

Comment: do note that `== false` can yield false positives, if the occurence falls down on `0` you're screwed

Comment: @ghost Yes please elaborate, judging from what i've tried. The if-statement is only executing once then applying its results to every page. I would like for the if-statement to apply its condition to every page, because they will all yield a different answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres my solution, using php and regexp:

```
<?php
 $venue_url_button = "Venue Website";
 if(preg_match('/discount(.*)/i',$forum_data['venue'['venue_url_text']) ) {
   $venue_url_button = "CLICK FOR DISCOUNTED HOTEL ROOMS"; }
else{
   $venue_url_button = "CLICK TO VISIT VENUE WEBSITE";
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
  if(stripos( $forum_data['venue_url_text'],"discount") == false) 
{
echo '<button class="btn" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> VISIT VENUE WEBSITE </button>'; 
}
else { 
echo '<button class="btn" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> VISIT DISCOUNTED VENUE</button>';
}
?>
```

I don't know if you're using button or input, so replace `<button>` with `<input type="submit" value="VISIT ..." />` if you want input instead of button.

UPDATE: sorry i coded it bad, updated

Comment: Also you dont explained too good, read the tips before asking. As well i thinked your if/else was not working

Comment: Thank you for responding, im using bootstrap's class="btn".

Comment: I need to work on explaining my code better. I'm using php as a template, so when i write code in one file  (view) all 50 of my web pages reflect the change. which is why the php is written inside of the html in a different structure like <?php if( )?> . Your php is more for static web pages my webpages are all dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<? if (stripos( $forum_data['venue_url_text'],"discount") !== false): ?>
    <a class="btn" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> VISIT DISCOUNTED VENUE </a>
<? else: ?>
   <a class="btn" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> VISIT VENUE WEBSITE </a>
<? endif; ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for responding, i'll try it out and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a colon (`:`) after `if` statement declaration, to change `elseif` condition with `else` and to put a semicolon (`;`) instead of colon after `endif`:

```
<?php if(stripos( $forum_data['venue_url_text'],"discount") == false): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $forum_data['venue']['venue_url']; ?>" class="btn" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> VISIT VENUE WEBSITE</a>
<?php else: ?>
<a href="<?php echo $forum_data['venue']['venue_url']; ?>" class="btn" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> VISIT DISCOUNTED VENUE</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, i didn't know that i will give it a shot.

Comment: I tried your code i got an error below.                                                                  

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '(' in /dev2/views/frontend/forum_single_2.php on line 618

Comment: @AngelC You are right! There's another error in your code: you have to use `else`, not `elseif`. I  will update answer now

Comment: Yes the error is no longer there, unfortunately the code is not changing the button text on all pages accordingly. It is either running the code once and giving the text of "visit venue discount". To every other page.